# What is the fastest way to make a pandas dataframe from a mongo cursor?

Tags: python, mongodb, list, list-comprehension, pymongo

I am running a mongo aggregation and trying to create a dataframe from the result. When I pull in about 6 months of data it works, but is slow. When I pull in a year's worth it seems to run forever, or is exponentially slower, but I believe my code is O(n), so I don't think that is the case.

```
cursor = coll.aggregate(pipeline_function(start_date, end_date),
                        allowDiskUse=True)
docs = [doc for doc in cursor]
df = pd.DataFrame(docs)
```

The aggregation takes 2s tops, the list comprehension takes about 11 minutes for 6months, but was at 90m for a year before I canceled it. The pd.DataFrame() call takes 3 minutes on 6 months of data.

To my knowledge a list comprehension is just for loop syntactic sugar, so this should essentially be:

```
my_list = []
for doc in cursor:
    my_list.append(doc)
```

Or something similar. I know the append() method has some overhead and so the list comp is faster, but to me this is O(n), so that tells me something funky has to be going on. I can pull all of the data in if I do it in two 6 month periods, so I do not think there is something wrong with the data in the later half of the year.

Why does this list comprehension seem to run infinitely when using more data?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does `df = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))` work better for you?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have tried that before, I want to say it is just slightly faster perhaps. I am running it now on the same 6 months to compare. It does not solve the whole "Pulling 1 year of data takes infinitely long", I know that much.

Comment: What's your memory capacity/usage? The symptoms remind me of performance collapse due to memory swapping.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I had it running for about 90 minutes once before canceling it. Reached about 40% memory utilization and 2% disk, so I don't think it was slowing down due to needing to write to disk. I have 16gb on my machine.

Comment: Is the MongoDB server running locally?

Comment: I'm also wondering how much IO time is being spent.  E.g., is transferring all the data via the cursor taking the bulk of the time, regardless of any post-processing?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No it is not. I have wondered if server latency is the main reason, and if perhaps it times out after a while and that is why pulling 1 year runs forever. I don't think any post-processing is happening. I am not doing anything to my knowledge. Just copying them to a list.